# config.xml override results in cart not visible?

Tags: php, javascript, xml, magento, overriding

I am building a second add to cart button with a different redirect on a magento platform.
The tutorial I've used is self explainatory. [See here](http://phprelated.myworks.ro/two-add-to-cart-buttons-with-different-redirect-actions-at-once-in-magnto/) 
It works okey as the redirect is in place.
The thing is: The cart itself doesnt show its page (cart.phtml) anymore.

Any idea how to fix this? Or where the problem exists?
If I remove the code underneath the cart is back again, as the redirect isn't working anymore.

File : config.xml

```
<global> 
        <routers> 
            <checkout> 
                <rewrite> 
                    <cart> 
                        <to>mycheckout/cart</to> 
                        <override_actions>true</override_actions> 
                        <actions> 
                            <add> 
                                <to>mycheckout/cart/add</to> 
                            </add> 
                        </actions> 
                    </cart> 
                </rewrite> 
            </checkout> 
        </routers> 
    </global>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your extension does not extend the cart controller that you are overwriting making it impossible to display the methods from original controller